# BigQuery COUNT column per ARRAY element

Tags: google-bigquery, query-optimization

I have a table with the following schema

```
id: STRING, NULLABLE
values: STRING, REPEATED

Row sample
----------------------------
| id    | values           |
----------------------------
| 123abc| [val1,val2,val3] |
----------------------------
```

I wanna count the number of ids per value.

```
Output sample
----------------------------
| value    | id_count      |
----------------------------
| val1     | 1             |
----------------------------
| val2     | 1             |
----------------------------
| val3     | 1             |
----------------------------
```

I've created the following query and it's working fine but I'm looking for a better way of doing it

```
SELECT value, COUNT(id) AS id_count
FROM(
    SELECT id, value
    FROM `myproject.mytable`, UNNEST(values) AS value
)
GROUP BY value
```

I'm trying to reduce the amount of data shuffled between the workers, so I looking for a way to get around the UNNEST function.

Comment: the query you presented  - cannot work fine! it cannot work at all! meantime, using `unnest` in such cases is the way to go - what makes you feel it is not good enough for you?

Comment: well, I'm concerned about the performance of this query or similar ones when applied to huge tables (20+ TB).

Comment: see the answer below then!

Comment: Your answer performs as mine in all ways, I'm looking for improvement. thanks anyway

Comment: oh, sure. this was not about performance as I mentioned already in above my comments - unnest is the right and only way  - my answer is more about how to better write your quesry to make it more readable and manageable :o)

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select value, count(distinct id) id_count
from `myproject.mytable`, unnest(values) AS value
group by value
```